# clojure cons vs conj with lazy-seq

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow, cons

Why does cons work in this context with lazy-seq, but conj doesn't?

This works:

```
(defn compound-interest [p i]
   (cons p (lazy-seq (compound-interest (* p (+ 1 i)) i))))
```

This doesn't (it gives a stack overflow exception):

```
(defn compound-interest2 [p i]
   (conj (lazy-seq (compound-interest2 (* p (+ 1 i)) i)) p))
```

Comment: For others who come here: my answer below is very detailed (perhaps too detailed) and may be confusing. Let me repeat the main point here: the semantics of `conj` require it to vary its behavior based on the collection type. That requires using a (polymorphic) method call on the collection object. A `LazySeq` handles that method call by delegating to its internal value, which requires realizing that internal value. In contrast, the semantics of cons don't require it to call any methods on the collection; it just has to store it in one field of a `Cons` object.

Comment: The last three paragraphs of the answer are particularly helpful.  Some people might want to read them first.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`(conj collection item)` adds `item` to `collection`. To do that, it needs to realize `collection`. (I'll explain why below.) So the recursive call happens immediately, rather than being deferred.

`(cons item collection)` creates a sequence which begins with `item`, followed by everything in `collection`. Significantly, it *doesn't* need to realize `collection`. So the recursive call will be deferred (because of using `lazy-seq`) until somebody tries to get the tail of the resulting sequence.

I'll explain how this works internally:

`cons` actually returns a `clojure.lang.Cons` object, which is what lazy sequences are made of. `conj` returns the same type of collection which you pass it (whether that is a list, vector, or whatever else). `conj` does this using a polymorphic Java method call on the collection itself. (See [line 524 of `clojure/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/612fba9159c6986cf875f97e086337f24a5ea3d8/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L524).)

What happens when that Java method call happens on the `clojure.lang.LazySeq` object which is returned by `lazy-seq`? (How `Cons` and `LazySeq` objects work together to form lazy sequences will become clearer below.) Look at [line 98 of `clojure/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/612fba9159c6986cf875f97e086337f24a5ea3d8/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L98). Notice it calls a method called `seq`. This is what realizes the value of the `LazySeq` (jump to [line 55](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/612fba9159c6986cf875f97e086337f24a5ea3d8/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java#L55) for the details).

So you could say that `conj` needs to know exactly what kind of collection you passed it, but `cons` doesn't. `cons` just requires that the "collection" argument is an `ISeq`.

Note that `Cons` objects in Clojure are different from "cons cells" in other Lisps -- in most Lisps, a "cons" is just an object which holds 2 pointers to other arbitrary objects. So you can use cons cells to build trees, and so on. A Clojure `Cons` takes an arbitrary `Object` as head, and an `ISeq` as tail. Since `Cons` itself implements `ISeq`, you can build sequences out of `Cons` objects, but they can just as well point to vectors, or lists, etc. (Note that a "list" in Clojure is a special type (`PersistentList`), and is *not* built from `Cons` objects.) `clojure.lang.LazySeq` *also* implements `ISeq`, so it can be used as the tail ("cdr" in Lisps) of a `Cons`. A `LazySeq` holds a reference to some code which *evaluates* to an `ISeq` of some kind, but it doesn't actually evaluate that code until required, and after it does evaluate the code, it caches the returned `ISeq` and delegates to it.

...is this all starting to make sense? Do you get the idea of how lazy sequences work? Basically, you start with a `LazySeq`. When the `LazySeq` is realized, it evaluates to a `Cons`, which points to another `LazySeq`. When that one is realized... you get the idea. So you get a chain of `LazySeq` objects, each holding (and delegating to) a `Cons`.

About the difference between "conses" and "lists" in Clojure, "lists" (`PersistentList` objects) contain a cached "length" field, so they can respond to `count` in O(1) time. This wouldn't work in other Lisps, because in most Lisps, "lists" are mutable. But in Clojure they are immutable, so caching the length works.

`Cons` objects in Clojure *don't* have a cached length -- if they did, how could they be used to implement lazy (and even infinite) sequences? If you try to take the `count` of a `Cons`, it just calls `count` on its tail, and then increments the result by 1.

Comment: Do you mean realizing item :)

Comment: @Ivan: No -- the order of arguments for `cons` and `conj` are opposite.

Comment: Yeap sorry I thought that he wrote `(conj p (lazy-seq (compound-interest2 (* p (+ 1 i)) i)))`.

Comment: So because `conj` works for all seqs (not just lists), it makes the blanket assumption that the collection must be realized (which would be needed if it were, say, a vector).  In theory, if the collection were a list though, `conj` could potentially work the same as `cons` right? (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: If `conj` was specialized to work only on lists, you couldn't use it on `LazySeq`s anyways, so the whole question would become irrelevant. Basically what it comes down to is: the semantics of `conj` require it to vary its behavior based on the collection type. That requires using a (polymorphic) method call on the collection object. `LazySeq` handles that method call by delegating to its internal value, which requires realizing that internal value. In contrast, the semantics of `cons` don't require it to call any methods on the collection; it just has to store it in one field of a `Cons`.

Comment: Great answer.  Among other things, it also provides an answer to another question: Why does Clojure have Cons, if it's already got PersistentLists, which have a length field missing from Cons'es?

Comment: @Mars isn't it because the missing length field allows for lazy evaluation? Just from what I read in the answer.

Comment: "... so they can respond to (count) in O(1) time."---are you sure?

Comment: @xando I haven't read the Clojure platform source code for a while. It may have changed in the meantime. Last time I read it, this is how it worked.