# Is there a function in the included Clojure libraries to split a string around another string?

Tags: string, split, clojure

I know that in `clojure.string` there is the `split` function which returns a sequence of the parts of the string excluding the given pattern.

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str-utils])
(str-utils/split "Yes, hello, this is dog yes hello it is me" #"hello")
;; -> ["Yes, " ", this is dog yes " " it is me"]
```

However, I'm trying to find a function that instead leaves the token as an element in the returned vector. So it would be like

```
(split-around "Yes, hello, this is dog yes hello it is me" #"hello")
;; -> ["Yes, " "hello" ", this is dog yes " "hello" " it is me"]
```

Is there a function that does this in any of the included libraries? Any in external libraries? I've been trying to write it myself but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Isn't the missing word implicit by any two adjacent items in the returned array? What did you try to do?

Comment: Excellent point!  That is the best answer.

Comment: @Shlomi yes, it is implicit but I need to have the string that was split on in the returned vec. In this case since the regex being split on is just a single word, yeah that works. But say the regex was `\[\[.*?\]\]`. In that case, there's a good chance there'll be things like `[[hello]]` and `[[yes]]` and I need to know what the text that was matched on is and where in the string it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also use the regex lookahead/lookbehind feature for that:

```
user> (clojure.string/split "Yes, hello, this is dog yes hello it is me" #"(?<=hello)|(?=hello)")
;;=> ["Yes, " "hello" ", this is dog yes " "hello" " it is me"]
```

you can read it as "split with zero-length string at point where preceding or subsequent word is 'hello'"

notice, that it also ignores the dangling empty strings for adjacent patterns and leading/trailing ones:

```
user> (clojure.string/split "helloYes, hello, this is dog yes hellohello it is mehello" #"(?<=hello)|(?=hello)")
;;=> ["hello"
;;    "Yes, "
;;    "hello"
;;    ", this is dog yes "
;;    "hello"
;;    "hello"
;;    " it is me"
;;    "hello"]
```

you can wrap it into a function like this, for example:

```
(defn split-around [source word]
  (let [word (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote word)]
    (->> (format "(?<=%s)|(?=%s)" word word)       
         re-pattern
         (clojure.string/split source))))
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Comment: Your `split-around` will fail if the word to split on contains regex metacharacters. If you want to generalize beyond "hello", use `Pattern/quote` to quote the metacharacters.

Comment: @amalloy fair enough

Comment: This doesn't always produce correct output. E.g. `(split-around "hahaha" "haha")` produces `["ha" "ha" "ha"]` but, based on `split`'s behavior, it should produce `["" "haha" "ha"]` or `["haha" "ha"]`.

Comment: Also notice that using both lookahead and lookbehind makes this solution slightly inefficient. For example, most occurrences of the separator-word will be recognized twice.

Answer (score 3):

```
(-> "Yes, hello, this is dog yes hello it is me"
    (str/replace #"hello" "~hello~")
    (str/split #"~"))
```

Comment: This will add extra empty strings if the searched-for string is exactly at the beginning of the input.

Comment: Yes, leetwinski has got it better.

Comment: This fails when the input contains `~`.

Answer (score 0):

Example using @Shlomi's solution:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (let [input-str "Yes, hello, this is dog yes hello it is me"
        segments  (mapv str/trim
                    (str/split input-str #"hello"))
        result    (interpose "hello" segments)]
    (is= segments ["Yes," ", this is dog yes" "it is me"])
    (is= result ["Yes," "hello" ", this is dog yes" "hello" "it is me"])))
```

---

### Update

Might be best to write a custom loop for this use case.  Something like:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str] ))

(defn strseg
  "Will segment a string like '<a><tgt><b><tgt><c>' at each occurrence of `tgt`, producing
   an output vector like [ <a> <tgt> <b> <tgt> <c> ]."
  [tgt source]
  (let [tgt-len  (count tgt)
        segments (loop [result []
                        src    source]
                   (if (empty? src)
                     result
                     (let [i (str/index-of src tgt)]
                       (if (nil? i)
                         (let [result-next (into result [src])
                               src-next    nil]
                           (recur result-next src-next))
                         (let [pre-tgt     (subs src 0 i)
                               result-next (into result [pre-tgt tgt])
                               src-next    (subs src (+ tgt-len i))]
                           (recur result-next src-next))))))
        result   (vec
                   (remove (fn [s] (or (nil? s)
                                     (empty? s)))
                     segments))]
    result))
```

with unit tests

```
(dotest
  (is= (strseg "hello" "Yes, hello, this is dog yes hello it is me")
    ["Yes, " "hello" ", this is dog yes " "hello" " it is me"] )
  (is= (strseg "hello" "hello")
    ["hello"])
  (is= (strseg "hello" "") [])
  (is= (strseg "hello" nil) [])
  (is= (strseg "hello" "hellohello") ["hello" "hello" ])
  (is= (strseg "hello" "abchellodefhelloxyz") ["abc" "hello" "def" "hello" "xyz" ])
  )
```

Comment: In this case you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between an empty string and "hello".

Comment: `strseg` doesn't terminate when `tgt` is empty and `source` isn't.

Comment: Good point!  The user should add an error check for that and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that avoids the problems with repetitive patterns and double recognitions present in leetwinski's answer (see my comments) and also computes the parts lazily-as-possible:

```
(defn partition-str [s sep]
  (->> s
       (re-seq
         (->> sep
              java.util.regex.Pattern/quote ; remove this to treat sep as a regex
              (format "((?s).*?)(?:(%s)|\\z)")
              re-pattern))
       (mapcat rest)
       (take-while some?)
       (remove empty?))) ; remove this to keep empty parts
```

**HOWEVER** this does not behave correctly/intuitively when the separator is/matches the empty string.

Another way could be to use both `re-seq` and `split` with the same pattern and interleave the resulting sequences as shown in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56571163/11419548). Unfortunately this way every occurrence of the separator will be recognized twice.

Perhaps a better approach would be to build on a more primitive basis using `re-matcher` and `re-find`.

Finally, to offer a straighter answer to the initial question, there is no such function in Clojure's standard library or any external library AFAIK. Moreover I don't know of any simple and completely unproblematic solution to this problem (especially with a regex-separator).

---

## UPDATE

Here is the best solution I can think of right now, working on a lower level, lazily and with a regex-separator:

```
(defn re-partition [re s]
  (let [mr (re-matcher re s)]
    ((fn rec [i]
       (lazy-seq
         (if-let [m (re-find mr)]
           (list* (subs s i (.start mr)) m (rec (.end mr)))
           (list (subs s i)))))
     0)))

(def re-partition+ (comp (partial remove empty?) re-partition))
```

Notice that we can (re)define:

```
(def re-split (comp (partial take-nth 2) re-partition))

(def re-seq (comp (partial take-nth 2) rest re-partition))
```